# What is best way to pass injections to base controller when using C# StructureMap.Mvc5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap, structuremap3

What is best way to get injections in base controller when using C# StructureMap.Mvc?

I can think of these 2 ways and don't know which is better.

1. From controller arguments to base controller arguments
   (Nice approach but becomes a mess when there are many controllers with many properties to be injected)
2. Don't use child controller and initiate all injections using ObjectFactory.CreateInstance() in base controller constructor
   (Very less code and manageable but not considered as good practice when Controller Injection is available)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please suggest other methods if you feel they are good.

Answer (score 0):

I think bother approaches are fine and you can use the mix of both. Of course depending in the situation.

A. I believe if your child Controller require a dependency to be injected, then use the Constructor injection. This way you Controller's constructor API is explicit and it should state what has been injected into the Controller. Easy to read, and easy for discoverability. If you try to hide your DI types in a factory you lose this nice API/discoverability. Use property injection when the dependencies are optional if you think so. You don't really have pass these to the base Controller unless all your Child Controllers use them.
If you think you overloading the types in your Controller, try to aggreagate those interfaces to a single types.

B. It is not advisable to directly use the Structure map ObjectFactory in your Controller. Your Controllers should be agnostics of any infrastructure DI work. You can make use a generic factory (in infrastructure) to create types which uses the ObjectFactory within. If your DI types are required by the base Controller you may use this factory to resolve those types.

The ideas, inject types only when/where they need. Avoid injecting types to Controllers when they don't use/need.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you available to you is setter injection via StructureMap's `ObjectFactory.BuildUp()` method.

It's worth mentioning that in StructureMap 3.1 the ObjectFactory has been deprecated in favour of injecting an instance of `IContainer`.

The examples would look like this:

**StructureMap 3.0 and below:**

```
public class BaseController {

    protected IMyExampleServer MyExampleService { get; set; };

    public BaseController() {
        ObjectFactory.BuildUp(this);
    }
    ....
}
```

**StructureMap 3.1+:**

```
public class BaseController {

    protected IMyExampleServer MyExampleService { get; set; };

    public BaseController(IContainer container) {
        container.ObjectFactory.BuildUp(this);
    }
    ....
}
```

Using StructureMap 3.1 would mean you'd only need to inject an instance of `IContainer` into your derived controller rather than each individual dependency that your base class requires.